# copying a query result into partition table (with python sdk)

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using airflow to run some ETLs from one partition table to another partition table, so the underlying client is python.

I don't quite understand about the jobs api, for the write_despositions flags in the partition table case
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs

The job will daily select a daily range of data from table 1 and copy into a partition table, table2, which write_desposition should I select?  Is `WRITE_TRUNCATE` appropriate?  If chosen, the job wouldn't truncate the table, that is remove previous days' data, but just create the new partition and copy the data into it, am I correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you will be inserting into specific partition (like `TABLE_NAME$YYYYMMDD`) - WRITE_TRUNCATE will replace existing data for [only] that partition with new data.  if you insert into table without specifying partition  - whole table will be truncated first